# Problema al mostrar un conjunto json en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, controller

Al momento de mandar un arreglo con formato JSON de mi Controlador hacia un archivo JavaScript por medio de AJAX, este me lo imprime como si fuera una cadena:

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Como se pueden dar cuenta, arriba me muestra un JSON que también envié desde el controlador pero aquí si me lo muestra bien.

Mi código del Controlador:

```
    public function alumnos()
{
    if (isset($_POST['id_grupo'])) { 
        $id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo'];
        $resultado = $this->model->alumnos($id_grupo);
        echo json_encode($resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }else{
        echo "No hay un POST";
    }
}
```

Mi código desde el archivo JavaScript:

```
function obtener_data(tbody, tabla) {
    $(tbody).on("click", "button.ver-alumnos", function () {
        let data = tabla.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        console.log(data);
        let id_grupo = data["id_grupo"];
        $.ajax({
            url: "dashboard/alumnos",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "id_grupo": id_grupo
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta)
            },
        })
    })
}
```

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda. Quiero enviarlo en formato JSON con la finalidad de poder utilizar el DataTable de forma correcta y no crear los registros desde el controlador de este modo:

```
public function alumnos()
{
    if (isset($_POST['id_grupo'])) { 
        $id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo'];
        $resultado = $this->model->alumnos($id_grupo);
        echo json_encode($resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
          foreach($resultado as $option){
            echo '<tr>'.'<td>'.$option["nombre"].'</td>'.'<td>'.$option["nocontrol"].'</td>'.'<td> <button type="button" class="ver-alumnos btn btn-primary">Estilos Aprendizaje</button>
            <button type="button" class="ver-alumnos btn btn-primary" onclick=""> Habilidades Estudio</button>
            </td>'.'</tr>';
        }  
    }else{
        echo "No hay un POST";
    }
}
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar la funcion `parse()` de `JSON` dentro de tu código js, te recomiendo dar un vistaso a esta página  [JSON.parse()](https://learncodeweb.com/javascript/how-to-decode-and-encode-json-data-in-javascript/). Y recuerda que es mucho más util agregar código que ss.

Comment: Parece ser que tienes un typo en tu objeto de configuración de Ajax. Intenta cambiar `datatype` por `dataType`.

Comment: Por favor, [no publiques imágenes con código fuente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/21), copia y pega directamente el código en tu pregunta. NO olvides incluir de la misma manera mensajes exactos de error. Un saludo.

Comment: @jachguate Ya corregí, gracias por la correción

Comment: @ricardo-dlc en efecto estaba mal escrito, muchas gracias!

Comment: Si indicas `dataType: 'json'`  en la petición Ajax (escrito correctamente claro está), no necesitas luego hacer  `JSON.parse()` al recibir los datos, porque el parse se hace sólo. Pero debes cuidar de que en PHP no salga por partalla nada más que un JSON que sea válido usando `json_encode`. Lo digo porque tienes también cosas como `echo <tr> .... button ... etc`  y en la parte del `else` tienes `echo "No hay un POST"` Todo eso es **incoherente** con tu `dataType` y te impedirá controlar los errores. Para los errores debes emitir también un JSON y verificar si tiene una clave error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si indicas `dataType: 'json'` en la petición Ajax (escrito correctamente claro está), no necesitas luego hacer `JSON.parse()` al recibir los datos, porque el parse se hace sólo, [como bien indica la documentación](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> `"json"`: Evaluates the response as JSON and returns a JavaScript
> object. Cross-domain "json" requests that have a callback placeholder,
> e.g. `?callback=?`, are performed using JSONP unless the request
> includes `jsonp: false` in its request options. The JSON data is
> parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse
> error is thrown. As of jQuery 1.9, an empty response is also rejected;
> the server should return a response of `null` or `{}` instead. (See
> json.org for more information on proper JSON formatting.)
>
> ---
>
> `"json"`: evalúa la respuesta como JSON y devuelve un objeto
> JavaScript. Solicitudes "json" entre dominios que tienen un marcador
> de posición de devolución de llamada, por ejemplo `?callback=?`, se
> realizan usando JSONP a menos que la solicitud incluya `jsonp: false`
> en sus opciones de solicitud. Los datos JSON se analizan de forma
> estricta; se rechaza cualquier JSON con formato incorrecto y se genera
> un error de análisis. A partir de jQuery 1.9, también se rechaza una
> respuesta vacía; el servidor debería devolver una respuesta `null` o
> `{}` en su lugar. (Consulte [json.org](https://json.org/) para obtener más información
> sobre el formato JSON adecuado).

Significa que **debes cuidar de que en PHP no salga por partalla nada más que un JSON que sea válido usando `json_encode`**. Eso vale también para **la parte del `else`, donde no estás emitiendo un JSON** y por tanto el código en el cliente fallará en caso de error.

Conviene también poner un encabezado antes de la salida, donde indiques el tipo de salida y la codificación. Ya que una codificación inadecuada podría producir un JSON inválido debido a caracteres extraños o mal interpretados.

```
    public function alumnos()
{
    if (isset($_POST['id_grupo'])) { 
        $id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo'];
        $resultado = $this->model->alumnos($id_grupo);
    }else{
        $resultado = array ("error"=>"No hay un POST");
    }
    header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    echo json_encode($resultado,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    exit;
}
```

En el cliente podrás verificar si en `respuesta` hay una clave `error` para actuar en consecuencia o mostrar los datos en caso contrario. Lo que hará el `if (respuesta.error)` aquí será encontrar errores de lógica en el código, no errores de red o de sintaxis u otros, sino errores que tú mismo has definido, como que el POST fue enviado vacío, que la consulta falló, que no hay conexión en la base de datos, etc.

```
function obtener_data(tbody, tabla) {
    $(tbody).on("click", "button.ver-alumnos", function () {
        let data = tabla.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        console.log(data);
        let id_grupo = data["id_grupo"];
        $.ajax({
            url: "dashboard/alumnos",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                "id_grupo": id_grupo
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (respuesta) {
                console.log(respuesta)
                //Si una clave error en la respuesta algo salió mal 
                if(respuesta.error) {
                    //Mostrar mensaje de error o actuar en consecuencia
                } else {
                    //Mostrar los datos
                }
            },
        })
    })
}
```